# How to Convert 'dict_items' Object to List

Tags: python-3.x

I am loading data from json files using load method and then putting the items in a new python object.

```
obj_1 = json.load(file)
obj_2 = obj_1.items()
```

When I run the code in python2, type(obj_2) is list. But when I run in python 3, type(obj_2) is 'dict_items'. Because of that when I run following code:

```
sorted_items = sorted (obj_2[1][1]['string'])
```

I'm getting this error in python 3:

> TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

In python 2 it runs fine. How can I solve this issue in python 3? I have found some related questions about this but the answers doesn't solve my particular case. I have tried to use **list(obj_2)** but it causes key error.
json file format is something like this:

```
  {
    "item_1": {
      "item_2": {
        "string": 111111,
        "string": 222222,
        "string": 333333,
        ................
        ................
      },
    },
  }
```

I want to sort the "item_2" contents according to the keys in ascending order.

Comment: Can you expand further on your file format?

Comment: dont call variabls after built ins - `dict()` is already take - so don't use `dict = ...` - you shadow the built in

Comment: use `somthing = list(obj_1.items())` or avoid indexing by altering your code

Comment: As the idiomatic way of doing what you want is a simple `list(obj_1.ites())`, I would say it will be more helpful if you focus on the `KeyError` you claim it gives...

Comment: I haven't use dict = in real code.

Answer (score 6):

simply

```
d = { .... }
l = list(d.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

making a for loop here is the best option i can think of.

```
object_list = []
for key, value in obj_2:
    entry = [key, value]
    object_list.append(entry)
```

that would store the key and value in a list that is inside another list.

**EDIT**

Found a better way to do it!

```py
my_dict = {"hello": "there", "how": "are you?"}
my_list = [[x, y] for x, y in my_dict.items()]

# out => [['hello', 'there'], ['how', 'are you?']]
```